# Как через проводник запустить файл с помощью python

Tags: python-3.x, explorer

Допустим я хочу запустить файл template.txt, прочитать его, отредактировать, в общем сделать всё, что делает текстовый редактор с ним. Как передать путь к этому файлу к .exe файлу, чтобы открыть его через проводник, а не через саму программу?

---

Приведу пример точнее:
Вот, у меня есть файл template.txt
[image: template.txt]

Слева от названия файла есть иконка, благодаря которой можно понять через какое приложение откроется файл (блокнот). Он отобразит текст, хранящийся в этом файле, но как-то он же получит сначала путь к этому файлу или я немного не в том направлении думаю? Так вот, как заменить этот блокнот на мой python-проект, который я преобразую в .exe, чтобы открылся ИМЕННО ЭТОТ файл, а также какие строки добавить в python-проект, чтобы узнать путь к этому файлу.